# Move Indicator Notification panel to extreme right in XFCE desktop session

Tags: indicator, xfce, xubuntu, notification-area, xfce-panel

I need help setting up indicator notification panel to extreme right.

I have set up [a global menu I found](http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/OMG+!+XFCE+Global+Menu+%5BOneiric+Only%5D?content=146102).

This is what I m getting:

[image: what i have]

and this is what I want it to look like, with notifications to the extreme right.

[image]

I want it to look like the unity panel.

Basically I want to turn it into a Mac clone.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right click on the panel and choose 'Panel' -> 'Panel Preferences'. Then go to 'Items' and add a seperator that you move with the arrows to the desired place. Close that window and do another right click now to the area where the seperator is located, enter the 'Properties' and choose 'Expand'.

Answer (score 3):

Change separator style to Transparent if you don't want to see it.

Comment: Good advice for an expended separator.

Answer (score 0):

To move indicator applet:

- Push and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd> and right click on indicator applet;
- Left click 'move';
- Left click and hold on indicator applet and slide along panel.